# Custom login page problem!

Tags: login

I am trying to make custom login page by adding 1 in functions.php and 2 into theme folder.
but I can't even execute the theme. 
I can activate the theme without 1 and 2. However, the site goes frozen both way trying to update the functions.php after pushing 2 to server and modifying the functions.php on dashboard, and trying to activate the theme after pushing the theme including 1,2 to server.
The file is available at www.lastech.com.au/green.zip 
I tried so many different way to sort this out but it is not working. I spent almost a week.
Please help me guys!

1.

```
function custom_login() { 
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/custom-login.css" />'; 
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login');
```

2.

```
custom-login.css file
```

My file is available at www.lastech.com.au/green.zip

Regards

BK

Comment: could you please clarify the question what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What i do is create a page normally in the dashboard, call it something like 'login', then use filters to replace the wordpress login url:

```
/**
* change http://www.google.ie to the url to your custom page, or anything you like
* @return string
*/
function my_login_url(){
    return "http://www.google.ie";
}
add_filter('login_url', 'my_login_url');
```

make sure you include it somewhere near the top of your functions file for themes or the index.php plugin_name.php file for plugins.

then anywhere in the wordpress blog wp_login_url() is called, using the above example, it will give a link to: 'http://www.google.ie'

Just came across this for renaming wp-admin:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/anyone-tried-wp-reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Replace the above with this:

```
    // Custom login css
function my_custom_login() {        
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='". get_bloginfo('template_directory') ."/custom-login.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />\n";
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');

    // Change the logo url from wordpress to the one you want   
function login_url(){       
    return home_url();      
}
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'login_url');

// Change the logo title from standard to the blog name
function login_title(){
    return get_bloginfo('name');
}
add_filter('login_headertitle', 'login_title');
```

Comment: You should have a look at the differences between actions and filters.